# How to find unused/dead code in java projects

Tags: java, refactoring, dead-code

What tools do you use to find unused/dead code in large java projects? Our product has been in development for some years, and it is getting very hard to manually detect code that is no longer in use. We do however try to delete as much unused code as possible.

Suggestions for general strategies/techniques (other than specific tools) are also appreciated.

**Edit:** Note that we already use code coverage tools (Clover, IntelliJ), but these are of little help. Dead code still has unit tests, and shows up as covered. I guess an ideal tool would identify clusters of code which have very little other code depending on it, allowing for docues manual inspection.

Comment: Keep the unit tests in a separate source tree (you should anyway) and run the coverage tools only on the live tree.

Comment: I would start with IDEA's ["Unused declaration" inspection](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6587932/27358) and uncheck **Include test sources**. Can you clarify what you mean when you say IDEA's "of little help"?

Comment: Ways to find dead code: 1) not linked by anything outside. 2) hasn't been used from outside even though linked in runtime. 3) Linked & Called but never used like dead variable. 4) logically unreachable state.

So linking, accessing over time, logic based, use after accessing.

Comment: Use IntelliJ Idea and my answer from here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22522013/how-find-all-unused-classes-in-intellij-idea/38244028#38244028
:)

Comment: Addition to David Mole's answer : see this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/6587932/1579667

Answer (score 43, accepted):

I would instrument the running system to keep logs of code usage, and then start inspecting code that is not used for months or years.

For example if you are interested in unused classes, all classes could be instrumented to log when instances are created. And then a small script could compare these logs against the complete list of classes to find unused classes.

Of course, if you go at the method level you should keep performance in mind. For example, the methods could only log their first use. I dont know how this is best done in Java. We have done this in Smalltalk, which is a dynamic language and thus allows for code modification at runtime. We instrument all methods with a logging call and uninstall the logging code after a method has been logged for the first time, thus after some time no more performance penalties occur. Maybe a similar thing can be done in Java with static boolean flags...

Comment: I like this answer but does anyone have an idea how to do this in Java without explicitly adding the logging in every class?  Maybe some 'Proxy' magic?

Comment: @Outlaw AOP seems to be perfect use case for this.

Comment: If you understand the application's classloading structure, you could use AOP on the classloader to track classload events.  This would be less invasive on a production system than advice before all constructors.

Comment: I've successfully used the java.lang.instrument.Instrumentation.getAllLoadedClasses() and addTransformer() methods to log which classes are loaded. The ClassFileTransformer doesn't modify the bytecode; it simply logs the class name. You must run a java agent in order to access an Instrumentation instance.

Comment: Are there any tools that could automate this using AOP and bytecode weaving or equivalent?

Comment: This answer is pretty good for a dynamic language but terrible for a static language which could do MUCH better.  With a staticly typed language (aside from reflection) you can know for sure exactly which methods are used and which are not, this is one of the biggest advantages of a statically typed language and you should use it rather than the fallable method as described here.

Comment: @BillK more reflection happens than you thinks.  E.g. Spring does quite a bit of magic under the covers, including reflection.  Your analysis tool must emulate that.

Comment: Actually most professional reflection based tools are moving to annotations instead of just string based reflection for exactly this reason.   Reflection takes away pretty much the entire advantage of a statically typed language.

Answer (score 228):

An Eclipse plugin that works reasonably well is [Unused Code Detector](http://www.ucdetector.org/).

It processes an entire project, or a specific file and shows various unused/dead code methods, as well as suggesting visibility changes (i.e. a public method that could be protected or private).

Comment: Looks nice but I wasn't able to get it working - the "Detect un... code" action is disabled and I didn't find way to enable it.

Comment: Do indeed find unused methods, BUT also find that my EJBs are being unused (while they are) because I'm using a business delegate pattern design

Comment: Does it still work on kepler ? releases say about eclipse 3.8 : http://www.ucdetector.org/releases.html

Comment: Seems to be in perfect working condition on Kepler.

Comment: I'm using: eclipse Luna M7 Release (4.4.0M7), on kubuntu 64 bit, and UCDetector caused eclipse to crash and not load my preferences -- had to uninstall the plug in.  ( June 2014)

Comment: UCDetector says it works on Eclipse 3.4 to 4.4, which includes Kepler.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend this tool. It is not efficient when it comes methods and static variables. Use Google CodePro instead.

Comment: Do you want to add a link to the marketplace https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/unnecessary-code-detector ? This makes it easier to install and answers the question whether it is supported on newer versions of Eclipse.

Comment: This tool looks good, mainly in detecting classes and public methods with zero references. Does this tool have a single view to show what all it has detected? I didn't find any. I have to browse each class to see what this tool has to say about that class, there is no single view.

Comment: UCD does not work for the methods those are being called from spring-web-flow. Is there any way to get similar 0 reference markers as we get in normal projects (non spring-web-flow)?

Answer (score 64):

[CodePro](https://developers.google.com/java-dev-tools/codepro/doc/) was recently released by Google with the Eclipse project.  It is free and highly effective. The plugin has a '[Find Dead Code](https://developers.google.com/java-dev-tools/codepro/html/tasks/maintopic)' feature with one/many entry point(s). Works pretty well.

Comment: Wont't work anymore with eclipse Kepler. After installing it successfully via update site, it makes eclipse crash every time.

Comment: Unfortunately, it looks like this tool doesn't realize of the existence of Spring, therefore, it will mark all my @Components as unused, wrongly

Comment: Become very old Doesn't work any more `Last updated this plugin March 27, 2012` https://developers.google.com/java-dev-tools/download-codepro

Comment: @Eildosa check this https://developers.google.com/java-dev-tools/codepro/html/tasks/maintopic

Comment: All links are outdated.

Comment: Unfortunately it appears that Google dumped the code on the Eclipse project and forgot all about it.

Comment: go to here to download to eclipse. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29390308/codepro-analytix-where-to-find-the-plugin-now-the-link-http-dl-google-com-ecl

Answer (score 33):

I'm suprised [ProGuard](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/) hasn't been mentioned here.  It's one of the most mature products around.

> [ProGuard](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/) is a free Java class file shrinker, optimizer, obfuscator,
>   and preverifier. It detects and removes unused classes, fields,
>   methods, and attributes. It optimizes bytecode and removes unused
>   instructions. It renames the remaining classes, fields, and methods
>   using short meaningless names. Finally, it preverifies the processed
>   code for Java 6 or for Java Micro Edition.
>
> Some uses of ProGuard are:
>
> - Creating more compact code, for smaller code archives, faster transfer across networks, faster loading, and smaller memory
>     footprints.
> - Making programs and libraries harder to reverse-engineer.
> - **Listing dead code, so it can be removed from the source code.**
> - Retargeting and preverifying existing class files for Java 6 or higher, to take full advantage of their faster class loading.

Here example for list dead code: https://www.guardsquare.com/en/products/proguard/manual/examples#deadcode

Comment: Providing a sample usage would make a better answer.

Comment: Reading the documentation, I see that it shrinks unused code, but I can't find anywhere where it *lists* it - agreed, an example, or link to the relevant section of the documentation, would be quite helpful!

Answer (score 25):

One thing I've been known to do in Eclipse, on a single class, is change all of its methods to private and then see what complaints I get.  For methods that are used, this will provoke errors, and I return them to the lowest access level I can.  For methods that are unused, this will provoke warnings about unused methods, and those can then be deleted.  And as a bonus, you often find some public methods that can and should be made private.

But it's very manual.

Comment: Maybe not the ideal answer but that's really clever.

Comment: This is clever... until you have a call to it from an unused code from another class.

Comment: Iterating over this method could remove huge swaths of code as one used method creates others once it's removed.

Answer (score 15):

Use a test coverage tool to instrument your codebase, then run the application itself, not the tests.

[Emma](http://emma.sourceforge.net/) and [Eclemma](http://www.eclemma.org/) will give you nice reports of what percentage of what classes are run for any given run of the code.

Comment: +1 for it is a good starting point but keep in mind that e. g. unused (yet declared) variables will come up green as well.

Answer (score 14):

We've started to use [Find Bugs](http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/) to help identify some of the funk in our codebase's target-rich environment for refactorings. I would also consider [Structure 101](http://www.headwaysoftware.com/index.php) to identify spots in your codebase's architecture that are too complicated, so you know where the real swamps are.

Comment: FindBugs cannot detect dead and unused code, only unused fields. See this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4721142/can-findbugs-detect-unused-public-methods/4752016#4752016).

Answer (score 13):

In theory, you can't deterministically find unused code.  Theres a mathematical proof of this (well, this is a special case of a more general theorem).  If you're curious, look up the Halting Problem.

This can manifest itself in Java code in many ways:

- Loading classes based on user input, config files, database entries, etc;
- Loading external code;
- Passing object trees to third party libraries;
- etc.

That being said, I use IDEA IntelliJ as my IDE of choice and it has extensive analysis tools for findign dependencies between modules, unused methods, unused members, unused classes, etc.  Its quite intelligent too like a private method that isn't called is tagged unused but a public method requires more extensive analysis.

Comment: Thank you for your input. We are using IntelliJ, and are getting some help there.

As for the Halting Problem and undecidability, I am familiar with the theory, but we do not necesarilly need a deterministic solution.

Comment: Opening sentence is too strong. As with the Halting Problem (also often misquoted/abused), there's no complete general solutions, but there are plenty of special cases that ARE feasible to detect.

Comment: While there isn't a general solution for languages with eval and/or reflection, there's lots of cases where code is provably unreachable.

Comment: Without reflection and with full source code any statically typed language should make it pretty easy to deterministically find all unused code.

Comment: You can't find that's provable unreachable by reflection or by external callers, but you can find code that's provable unreachable statically from a given entry point or set of entry points

Answer (score 9):

In Eclipse Goto Windows > Preferences > Java > Compiler > Errors/Warnings
and change all of them to errors. Fix all the errors. This is the simplest way. The beauty is that this will allow you to clean up the code as you write.

Screenshot Eclipse Code :

[image]

Answer (score 5):

IntelliJ has code analysis tools for detecting code which is unused.  You should try making as many fields/methods/classes as non-public as possible and that will show up more unused methods/fields/classes

I would also try to locate duplicate code as a way of reducing code volume.

My last suggestion is try to find open source code which if used would make your code simpler.

Comment: Any examples of what these tools are?

Comment: @orbfish You can run `Analyse` => `Run inspection by name` => `unused`

Answer (score 5):

The Structure101 [slice perspective](http://www.headwaysoftware.com/help/java/index.html?perspectives_slice.html) will give a list (and dependency graph) of any "orphans" or "orphan [groups](http://www.headwaysoftware.com/help/java/index.html?perspectives_group.html)" of classes or packages that have no dependencies to or from the "main" cluster.

Comment: Does this work for instance variables / methods within a class?

Comment: How do I know if this is supposed to work with e.g. Eclipse 4.3?

Answer (score 3):

DCD is not a plugin for some IDE but can be run from ant or standalone. It looks like a static tool and [it can do what PMD and FindBugs can't](http://java.net/projects/dcd/pages/Alternatives). I will try it.

P.S. As mentioned in a comment below, the Project lives now in [GitHub](https://github.com/evernat/dead-code-detector).

Comment: This should go down as a comment not answer

Comment: Please update your answer to remove your statement that DCD "looks dead now". [Version 2.1 was released 12 days ago](https://github.com/evernat/dead-code-detector/releases). Also, the link in your answer doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

There are tools which profile code and provide code coverage data. This lets you see (as code is run) how much of it is being called. You can get any of these tools to find out how much orphan code you have.

Answer (score 2):

- FindBugs is excellent for this sort of thing.
- PMD (Project Mess Detector) is another tool that can be used.

However, neither can find **public static methods** that are unused in a workspace. If anyone knows of such a tool then please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

User coverage tools, such as EMMA. But it's not static tool (i.e. it requires to actually run the application through regression testing, and through all possible error cases, which is, well, impossible :) )

Still, EMMA is very useful.

Answer (score 1):

Code coverage tools, such as Emma, Cobertura, and Clover, will instrument your code and record which parts of it gets invoked by running a suite of tests. This is very useful, and should be an integral part of your development process. It will help you identify how well your test suite covers your code.

However, this is not the same as identifying real dead code. It only identifies code that is covered (or not covered) by tests. This can give you false positives (if your tests do not cover all scenarios) as well as false negatives (if your tests access code that is actually never used in a real world scenario).

I imagine the best way to really identify dead code would be to instrument your code with a coverage tool in a live running environment and to analyse code coverage over an extended period of time.

If you are runnning in a load balanced redundant environment (and if not, why not?) then I suppose it would make sense to only instrument one instance of your application and to configure your load balancer such that a random, but small, portion of your users run on your instrumented instance. If you do this over an extended period of time (to make sure that you have covered all real world usage scenarios - such seasonal variations), you should be able to see exactly which areas of your code are accessed under real world usage and which parts are really never accessed and hence dead code.

I have never personally seen this done, and do not know how the aforementioned tools can be used to instrument and analyse code that is not being invoked through a test suite - but I am sure they can be.

Answer (score 1):

There is a Java project - [Dead Code Detector](https://blogs.oracle.com/geertjan/entry/dead_code_detection_with_netbeans) (DCD). For source code it doesn't seem to work well, but for .jar file - it's really good. Plus you can filter by class and by method.

Answer (score 1):

**Netbeans**  here is a plugin for Netbeans [dead code detector](http://plugins.netbeans.org/plugin/50005/dead-code-detector).

It would be better if it could link to and highlight the unused code. You can vote and comment here: [Bug 181458 - Find unused public classes, methods, fields](https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=181458)

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse can show/highlight code that can't be reached. JUnit can show you code coverage, but you'd need some tests and have to decide if the relevant test is missing or the code is really unused.

Comment: Eclipse will only tell you if the scope of the method is local (ie. private); and even then you can't be 100% sure... with reflection private method could be called from the outside.

Answer (score 0):

I found Clover coverage tool which instruments code and highlights the code that is used and that is unused. Unlike Google CodePro Analytics, it also works for WebApplications (as per my experience and I may be incorrect about Google CodePro).

The only drawback that I noticed is that it does not takes Java interfaces into account.

Comment: Afaict, it's a non-free server side CI tool.

Answer (score 0):

I use Doxygen to develop a method call map to locate methods that are never called. On the graph you will find islands of method clusters without callers. This doesn't work for libraries since you need always start from some main entry point.