# Analysing a project to find out what it's not used

Tags: eclipse

Is there a way in eclipse to analyse a project to find out which methods or functions or variables are not used, like a getter for example?

Comment: http://www.ucdetector.org/

Comment: Go through these posts:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4721142/can-findbugs-detect-unused-public-methods

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/162551/how-to-find-unused-dead-code-in-java-projects

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/665563/find-unused-classes-in-a-java-eclipse-project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved, thanks to JB Nizet.

UCDetector (Unnecessary Code Detector, http://ucdetector.org/) was what I was looking for.