# How to purge unused source/class files from Directory tree

Tags: java

We have about 280 Java source code spread over 10 packages, and a bunch of txt and image files for a software project. Quite a few of them are not being used currently. They do not break the system, since we can just do a "javac */*/*.java" and "jar cmf metafile " to build up the executable jar which works. The question:

How do we find the class files never accessed, or image/txt files never used as resources in the jar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the Unused Code detector: http://www.ucdetector.org/

Answer (score 1):

It would be very hard to determine which image/txt files are never used, as they can be loaded in a variety of manners.  A good bet for the image/txt files is to search for the name of each file in your code; if it is not there, it *might* not be being used; remember, the name of the file could be being generated programmatically and then loaded.

I recently had to do something similar for a game project.  Because content could be brought in via a variety of means, removing unused content took a lot of trial and error.

There are plugins for eclipse that can find unused code.

Answer (score 0):

It has been answered in [How to find unused/dead code in java projects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/162551/how-to-find-unused-dead-code-in-java-projects).

For the images, I would write a small program, pseudocode would look like:

```
//list image names
//for each image name
    //find ocurrences in other files
```