# How to use IntelliJ IDEA to find all unused code?

Tags: java, refactoring, intellij-idea, code-metrics, code-inspection

When I am in a .java file, the unused code is usually grayed out or has a green underline saying this code will probably (probably because of some weird JNI/Reflection corner cases) be unused. But I have this project with thousands of Java files and I want to find **all instances** of such probable-unused code. How can I do that in IntelliJ IDEA?

Comment: The answer given is right, but it's just a pity that there is no way to get all unused /dead code inside a project + a button to remove it all. That would be helpful !

Comment: @Snicolas right-click on the inspection result (Declaration redundancy->Unused declaration) and choose "Safe delete".

Comment: Or if you want button, there's the light-bulb in the left toolbar.

Comment: You may check my answer on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22522013/how-find-all-unused-classes-in-intellij-idea/38244028#38244028. There you can find how to filter the results to see only those, which you really wanted.

Comment: Is there a way of automating IntelliJ's unused code detection mechanism in a pull request ? When a pull request is created, so it will scan through the files in that PR, and show me the unused code.

Answer (score 597, accepted):

Just use `Analyze | Inspect Code` with appropriate inspection enabled (**Unused declaration** under **Declaration redundancy** group).

Using IntelliJ 11 CE you can now "Analyze | Run Inspection by Name ... | Unused declaration"

Comment: Just a correction for future readers: IDEA 12.1.6, at least, does indeed have it under Analyze --> Inspect Code

Comment: @CrazyCoder This shows unused fields and methods too, any way to show only unused classes?

Comment: @BenClayton try `Unused symbol` inspection with appropriate options.

Comment: My 2 cents: on IntelliJ 2016.3.4 the option is under Analyze > Run Inspection By Name. -- My 5 cents: if you're working on a big project and you're running the feature for the whole project, I suggest you to do it before lunch or at the end of the day, because it can take 1h+ to complete. Or, maybe, you can do it during the work hours and say to your boss that you're running an analyzer... and you can get some rest for free! :)

Comment: @BenClayton and the rest, looking just for unused classes....http://stackoverflow.com/a/38244028/2541200

Comment: If you are trying to find unused methods in a *Kotlin* project, run the `Unused symbol` inspection. Looks like the `Unused declaration` only works in Java projects.

Comment: Do you know if I can adjust search not to include groovy test? I tried configuration proposed, directory marked as test directory but it's still considers code as "used"

Answer (score 128):

In newer versions of IntelliJ it's under **Code -> Analyze Code -> Run Inspection by Name**.

In IntelliJ versions before that, you should run it from **Analyze -> Run Inspection By Name**:

[image]

Than, pick **Unused declaration**:

[image]

And finally, **uncheck** the **Include test sources**:

[image]

Comment: In newer versions of IntelliJ it's under Code | Analyze Code | Run Inspection by Name

Answer (score 4):

After you've run the Inspect by Name, select all the locations, and make use of the *Apply quick fixes to all the problems* drop-down, and use either (or both) of *Delete unused parameter(s)* and *Safe Delete*.

Don't forget to hit *Do Refactor* afterwards.

Then you'll need to run another analysis, as the refactored code will no doubt reveal more unused declarations.

[image: Apply quick fixes to all the problems]

Answer (score 4):

A picture is worth a thousand words! *IntelliJ IDEA 2022.x.x*

- Go to the **code tab, analyze code**,  and **run inspection by name**.

[image: navigation]

- Select what you need

[image: settings]

Comment: As of today (WebStorm Giraffe) there is no Inspection Options section