# How to remove unused imports in Intellij IDEA on commit?

Tags: java, import, automation, intellij-idea

Is there a way to remove unused imports in Intellij IDEA on commit?

It is not very optimal to do it manually, <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>O</kbd> helps but it's still manual.

Comment: `ctrl + alt + l` will send my pc to sleep..LOL. linux btw.

Comment: alt + control + o   : works best on Mac

Comment: @Wuaner you can disable it through  `All Settings` => `Keyboards` => `Shortcuts` . By the way <kbd>ctrl</kbd> <kbd>alt</kbd>  <kbd>l</kbd>  is used to format the code in `Intellij`

Comment: alt + control + o working in windows + IDEA

Comment: Mac: option + control + o

Answer (score 118, accepted):

When you commit, tick the `Optimize imports` option on the right.  This will become the default until you change it.

I prefer using the `Reformat code` option as well.

Comment: You can also set the option for "Optimize imports on the fly", under the `Editor > Auto Import` section

Comment: That is cool, but can drive you crazy if it imports the wrong class.

Comment: that is what the second option for "Add unambiguous imports on the fly" is for :) You can disable the first and only enable the unambiguous setting.

Comment: True, but sometimes you use a class which is fine in one module but isn't in the dependencies of another and you end up including something under `com.sun.*` or `sun.*`

Comment: Not sure if I follow what you mean, but both settings will only add imports for classes on the classpath. You can configure classes or packages to be excluded from automatic import also.

Comment: This is true, but it much easier to do this when there is multiple options. When there is automatically one choice, its trickier to find how to exclude a package.

Answer (score 170):

If you are using IntelliJ IDEA or Android Studio:

[image: Android optimize imports]

Go to **Settings <kbd>></kbd> Editor <kbd>></kbd> General <kbd>></kbd>Auto Import** and check the **Optimize imports on the fly** checkbox.

Comment: I just tried and it does not remove unused imports (on IDEA 2017.2.4)

Comment: For me its Preferences > Editor > General > Auto Import, and check the "Optimize imports on the fly". It works. I'm using IntelliJ IDEA 2020.1.4

Answer (score 50):

In Mac IntelliJ IDEA, the command is <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>Option</kbd> + <kbd>O</kbd>

For some older versions it is apparently <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Option</kbd> + <kbd>O</kbd>.

(Letter O not Zero 0) on the latest version 2019.x

Comment: and ctrl+alt+o for Windows

Comment: Update for 2020. We use ctrl + option + o (macOS)

Answer (score 48):

**Choose the project/module** you want to remove unused import from in Project view. Then from **Code** menu choose **Optimize imports** and confirm with **Run**. The imports will be cleaned in whole project/module.

Answer (score 45):

You can check checkbox in the commit dialog.

[image]

You can use settings to automatically optimize imports since 11.1 and above.

[image]

Answer (score 15):

In mac book

IntelliJ

Control + Option + o (not a zero, letter "o")

Answer (score 9):

To remove the unused imports in windows. please use the default key combination below.

**`CTRL + ALT + O    ---> to remove the unused imports in windows.`**

However, you can also change the keymap of **"Optimize Imports" in settings.**

Answer (score 8):

Or you can do the following shortcut :

**MAC** : Shift + Command + A (Enter Action menu pops up)

And write : `Optimize Imports`

Answer (score 5):

If you want to use `CTRL + Alt + L` (remove unused imports while formatting code), you can use `CTRL + Alt + Shift + L` (once) and there is a checkbox in the popup you should check

[image]

Answer (score 3):

`File/Settings/Inpsections/Imports` and change "Unused import" to Error.  This marks them more clearly in the Inspections gutter and the Inspection Results panel.

Answer (score 2):

In IntelliJ, select the project you want to optimize imports on, go to **Code** menu and choose **Optimize imports** and a small **Optimize Imports** popup window will appear. On the popup window you need to click on **Run** button. Or alternatively, on IntelliJ on Mac, you can use a keyboard short cut **<kbd>Option</kbd> + <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>O</kbd>**

Comment: Its Option+ **Control** +O

Answer (score 1):

Now you also have the option to just search for unused imports

- Code -> Analyze Code -> Run Inspection by Name.
- Unused Import
- Whole Project

Source: [How to use IntelliJ IDEA to find all unused code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6587729/how-to-use-intellij-idea-to-find-all-unused-code)