# How to find unused methods using IntelliJ?

Tags: intellij-idea

Upon analysis, `IntelliJ` finds unused methods, but i need to be in the class in question. Additionally the only way i find about is by scrolling through the code to find a method with greyed out name.

Is there a way one can run a search across project to find unused methods?

Additionally, if `A` calls `B` and `A` is unused, is it possible to mark `B` as unused as well, as part of a single search?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use IntelliJ IDEA to find all unused code?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6587729/how-to-use-intellij-idea-to-find-all-unused-code)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can do this through "Inspect Code".

Go to Analyze -> Inspect Code, select the default project, and allow it to run.  You'll get a result set similar to this.

[image: Left side of result set.]
[image: Right side of result set.]

This is a dummy project I use for formatting code and experimenting with questions asked on SO.  I had completely *forgotten* that I had a `StackOverflow` class here, but the inspection found that it was unused after all.