# How to use IntelliJ IDEA to find all unused action script classes?

Tags: actionscript-3, intellij-idea

I have been a happy IntelliJ IDEA user for a long time but I have this question. How to use IntelliJ IDEA to find all unused action script classes?

Comment: Run code inspections across the project like described in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6587932/104891).