# How to run inspection for finding all unused classes?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, dead-code

When a new class has just been created, IntelliJ Idea marks it as unused and suggests to delete it. But where does this inspection actually live? I tried to run inspection by name and found "Unused Declaration" which has a dozen (in my opinion) parameters and a very strange finding algorithm. For example, every class which is found actually used somewhere. Is there a way to run an inspection which reports completely unused classes?

Comment: "every class which is foun actually used somewhere" Can you show an example of this?

Comment: No I think. I can not copy and paste entire project to stackoveflow. Try this inspection on your project and see the results.

Comment: You do not need to copy and paste an entire project. Just show one class and where it is used.

Comment: Right Click on Project - Analyze - Inspect Code - Whole Project
In Results: Go to, Declaration redundancy - Unused declaration.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22522013/how-find-all-unused-classes-in-intellij-idea