# check mutiple method usage at once in intellij

Tags: intellij-idea, intellij-plugin

is it possible to check the usage for multiple methods in a class at once in Intellij?
For example, class A has 100 methods. Instead of going over each single method and check if it is used, can we actually check some or all of usages for methods in this class at once in Intellij?

Comment: Analyze | Inspect Code.

Comment: @CrazyCoder it does not work for me. Intellij showed "no suspicious code found"

Comment: Please share the sample code and the inspection profile you are using to reproduce the problem.

Comment: See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6587932/104891.

Comment: The method name should be grey if it isnt used at all... does this indicate what you are looking for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are purely looking for methods that are unused, and there are no errors in the source, you can just use F2 to jump between them.

Unused methods will be highlighted grey, with an underline.