# How to find unused imports in intellij

Tags: intellij-idea

Similar questions have been asked.  Using "optimize imports" reorders (as we all know) and causes me issues with code reviews as thousands of files are changed. No one wants to review such a pull request.

So, finding unused imports would be nice.  Removing them automagically without reordering would be better.

Comment: Well when reviewing my own feature branches I usually do a file by file diff, and manually remove unused import lines (which are greyed out automatically by IntelliJ).

Comment: Same as for other code problems: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6587932/104891.

Answer (score 1):

At least in PHPStorm you can do `Code > Inspect Code...`, this will find all problems and there will be section `PHP > Unused Symbols > Unused Imports` and you can right-click to remove all of them at once.

[image]

Comment: ooo thanks I'll try that