# Remove dead code in JSP

Tags: java, javascript, jsp, dead-code

I have a big project with a lot of code (most in JSP) and I like to find a tool that can remove dead code from all the JSP. Do you know or recommended me a good tool?

I've looked into lots of tools that do this well for pure Java projects, but nothing seems to really handle projects with JSP and JavaScript.

Comment: What would you define as dead code?

Comment: The code that is never used or code than "can never run"... for example a function that is defined but whose name is never mentioned in any JSP

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/162551/how-to-find-unused-dead-code-in-java-projects

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Theoretically ProGuard can process WAR files, how about running you code through that selecting the options to remove redundant code?