# How to find a list of methods used only within tests

Tags: java, unit-testing, refactoring, automated-refactoring

I'm refactoring a java project. It seems that there are a lot of code (methods) used only within unit tests.

Is there a tool which could find all those methods?

So I'll need to find a list of methods within `com.XXX` projects which are:

1. used only within `com.XXX.test.XXX` classes
2. not marked with JMX autowired annotation
3. classes themselves are not in `com.XXX.test` packages

I'd better to have it as a list, so I could attach it into the ticket within task-tracking system (bugzilla, jira)

I think that reflection could be used, but don't like to reinvent the wheel.
Maybe there is a lib for that?

PS. there is a note that [How to find unused/dead code in java projects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/162551/how-to-find-unused-dead-code-in-java-projects) question is the same, but there is a slight difference: the code is used, but in XXXTestXXX.java files.